# Find how many cores Windows is using in msinfo32

Tags: windows, cpu

I run Windows in a virtual machine. I have msinfo32 output and it is not showing how many cores it is using. It just shows:

[image]

Is there any other place in the msinfo output that says how many logical processors are being used? I can **only** use the output of the msinfo utility (and not Task Manager for example, since I want to be able to exclude possible bugs from third party tools that are being used by clients).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, the number of cores should be listed where you are looking. If not, your Windows installation should store this in the NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS environment variable, which can be accessed via msinfo32 with the following instructions:

1. Open **msinfo32** (**Start** -> **Run** -> **msinfo32**)
2. On the left-hand side, expand **Software Environment**
3. Select **Environment Variables**
4. Look at the Variable **NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS**

[image]

Comment: Bear in mind though that this does not tell you anything about the topology. It could be 2 Cores with 2 Threads each or 4 Cores or even 4 1-Core CPUs.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This asker is not trying to define the topology though. Baijan is just trying to use msinfo32 to identify how many cores are allocated to a given VM instance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to search for Processor inside the MSINFO application.

[image: I was able to find the # of cores in my msinfo32]

If MSINFO32 doesn't report a number of cores and logical processors, then it's running on a single processor.

Doing a little googling the only thing I could find close to your named processor above was a Celeron chip which would only = 1 core.  I was not able to find the exact x86 Family 6 Model 47 Stepping 2 processor.

You can use Powershell to find that info if you want.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor NumberOfCores
```

Comment: OP: "I can only use the output of the msinfo utility"

Comment: Oops, I see that now.  Why use anything but powershell these days???